# How do partially protonated sulfate ligands affect a metal's charge?

Tags: coordination-compounds, transition-metals, oxidation-state

I'm currently reviewing the Periana-Catalytica system and I have a question about one of the intermediates, namely $\ce{[(bpym)Pt(OSO3H)2]^+}$, which is found in [the following tutorial review](http://pubs.rsc.org/en/Content/ArticleLanding/2013/CS/C3CS60120J#!divAbstract). How do the $\ce{OSO3H}$ ligands affect the oxidation state of the metal? If I count each of these ligands as a monoanionic ligand, and also factor in the positive charge of the complex, wouldn't the oxidation state of the metal be +3? This seems a bit strange to me, seeing as Pt typically has oxidation states of +2 or +4, but never +3.

Comment: http://www.wag.caltech.edu/publications/sup/pdf/512.pdf

Comment: So judging from the complexes I see in Figure 3, I've deduced that $OSO_{3}H$ is a monoanionic ligand. Am I correct?

Comment: Yeah, your right. And there's no problem with intermediate on +3 oxidation.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. So is the +3 oxidation state not really a problem for Pt, per se--it's only not really seen because it's an intermediate and is therefore very transitory?

Comment: There are also Pt (III) compounds, at least dinuclear ones http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ic00137a074